Propagation on simple connected graph
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple connected graph, where all vertices can be "active" or "inactive". Then let $A \subseteq V$ be an initial set of active vertices. Now we let the graph evolve according to the following rules: 1. At each instant, all inactive neighbors of active nodes become active. 2. All currently active nodes become inactive.
What I aim to prove is that after some time, the active and inactive nodes will form two sets that alternate between being active and inactive as time progresses. I thought about defining $\phi(A)=N(A) \backslash A$, which determines the active vertices on the next iteration ($N(A)$ denotes the neighbors of the set $A$) given that $A$ are the active vertices and then trying to show that $\phi^k(A)=\phi^{k+2}(A)$ for some $k$.
The fact that eventually the process enters a cycle is evident because the number of possible states is finite and each state determines the next state uniquely, but I am unable to find a proof that this cycle must be of length 2. Maybe the way to go would be to show that starting from an initial set $A$ there are sets $S, T$ that partition $V$ such that $\phi(S)=T$, $\phi(T)=S$ and $S=\phi^k(A)$. Thanks in advance for any help that you can give me.

First exclude the case where all vertices are inactive. Then exclude the case where all vertices are active because they will all become inactive in the next step.
In the remaining cases (i.e., at least one vertex of either state), if a pair of adjacent vertices ever assume distinct states, then they will alternate forever after.
For any given vertex consider the distance to the nearest vertex with a different state as a function of time. Observe that it is nonincreasing, and if it is greater than 1 it must decrease over the next two iterations.
